# Remove old games from Steam panel entry

Tags: steam

I had a couple of games on my old PC, and now switched to another one. Now, despite having only 4 games installed, the entry on the panel *(aka Linux menu bar)(that thing with all games, the 5 major categories in Steam, etc)* is spammed with 20 games or so. How do I remove them? I've heard of a way of doing it via the library, but they're not in the library. What to do now? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't selected the option to show all games and not just the ones that are installed?

Comment: Are you talking about the jump list when you right click Steam in the menu bar?

Comment: Exactly. There's like 30 games in there. Many of which won't even run on my PC because they're not made for SteamOS/Linux.

Comment: A similar question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/steam-and-the-recently-played-games-jump-list