# Steam and recently played games jump list

Tags: steam

A couple of days ago Steam stopped displaying recently played games when I right click on the tab on the taskbar.

I've tried doing all the things suggested [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/steam-and-the-recently-played-games-jump-list) but none has worked.

Can anybody help me please? I'm on the edge of the desperation.

Comment: Have you changed anything on your system recently? Installed something, changed settings somewhere. Have you tried to see if your AV is the culprit?

Comment: I didn't change or install anything, I don't use any AV as I'm tech savvy enough to know what I'm doing and to protect myself against internet threats. The only thing that had changed is Steam which updated itself, but I've been talking with other users who told me they don't have this issue. I've even tried to delete everything in the Steam folder except steam.exe, userdata and steamapps, but it didn't help.

Comment: I would strongly suggest doing at least one scan with trustworthy AV software right now. Tech savvyness does not protect against everything, and you do not limit yourself to a whitelist of sites (e.g. you asked a question here). I would also suggest clearing the Download Cache (as seen [here](https://heroesandgenerals.com/support/steam/how-to-refresh-your-steam-files-clear-download-cache/)), as it clears more cache than the name suggests. If you search for Steam by clicking the button next to home, and right-click the executable, do you see recently played games there?

Comment: I've already done a scan, of course! And already cleared my download cache.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an UI limitation with the jump lists. Unfortunately they're limited to 10 entries per program. By default, Steam provides several entries such as "Shop", "Friends", "Quit Steam", etc. that will eat up that number.

In my case, I've only had space for 2 recent (or pinned) games.

To solve this, you'll have to remove some of the default Steam entries that you don't use anyway.

Go to **Settings**, **Interface**, and then find the button **Taskbar Preferences** on the bottom. Click it, unselect all entries you don't use in the jump list anyway, and you'll once again get one or more recent games entries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any games pinned in the jump list (the menu that appears when you right-click on the taskbar icon)?

I've noticed that pinning two or more games in the jump list will remove the "Recent" section, but unpinning games until I have one or zero will cause the Recent section to reappear.

Comment: I don't have any. I just can't see any game at all.